# Is this a .conkerorrc error ?

Tags: conkeror

> Console error: [JavaScript Error: "TypeError: props is undefined"
>   {file: "chrome://conkeror/content/minibuffer-read.js" line: 71}]
>   Category: chrome javascript Console error: [JavaScript Error:
>   "TypeError: props is undefined" {file:
>   "chrome://conkeror/content/minibuffer-read.js" line: 73}]   Category:
>   chrome javascript

Conkeror still runs, but cant get anything past the first line of my .conkerorrc to run , which is just the following :

```
//set default webjump
read_url_handler_list = [read_url_make_default_webjump_handler("google")];
```

Comment: @Rndm thanks for the edit (sorry i just threw it up there without formating)  its a weird error!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is a problem in your rc.  You would see this error if you are running a version of Conkeror older than November 2013, on a version of XULRunner 22 or higher.  If this is the case, update your Conkeror to a newer version.  The relevant issue on the Conkeror bug tracker is here: http://bugs.conkeror.org/issue454 and the commit that addressed this problem is commit 38b6279c2053854c2e8f24e70facb5328d9f170c of November 7, 2013.